# Gutenberg inline style messing up the navigation when I add a list to a page

Tags: css, block-editor, list

This is sort of weird. I have a set of pages and the navigation looks the same on all but one page. After trial/error I was able to narrow it down to having a list on my page. As soon as I add a list to the page it appears that Gutenberg applies an inline style called "wp-block-list-inline-css" and that interferes with the navigation because the inline style is ul.has-background{padding:1.25em 2.375em} which impacts the navigation as well. I don't see the 1.25em anywhere in the theme files. Any ideas on how to either prevent the style injection or how to change the style?

Comment: I was able to override it by getting a bit more specific in the theme style, adding this line:  
.wp-block-navigation__responsive-container-content ul {padding:0;}

Comment: That's a mystery for me as well. This `ul.has-background` rule is too wide as it impacts things it's not supposed to. And I don't understand either the meaning of applying an `.has-background` class where there is no background. Looks like a collision between both Navigation and List blocks

Comment: That's the bug reported here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/50486